# How can I get all the properties in Typescript Class with Optional properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have

```
class MyType {
  property1?: string,
  property2?: string
}
```

which all the properties are OPTIONAL.

How can I get an array of property names like:

```
["property1", "property2"]
```

I have tried

```
console.log(Object.keys(new MyType()))
```

which will return an empty array, because all the properties are optional.

Comment: If you want an a runtime value, like your array above, which contains all the optional property keys you are out of luck. Optionality is part of the type system and is fully erased.

Answer (score 1):

After transpiled, TS compiler will erase the optional properties. See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAVeAHAptA3gKGtFATgPboEAu8AjAPwBc0EZBAlgHYDmu+xpFATHQZM2nAL7ZswIqwhEQaAHQgi7ABQB5AEYArNMDIKA1mngRVrNAHc4SVGlUBKJ0A)

TS:

```
class MyType {
  property1?: string
  property2?: string
}

console.log(Object.keys(new MyType()))
```

transpiled JS:

```js
"use strict";
class MyType {
}
console.log(Object.keys(new MyType()));
```

That's why you got an empty array.